# How do I write a newly-created AVMutableComposition to disk with minimal recompression?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, avfoundation

I've built an `AVMutableComposition` with a video track and audio track, and concatenated (sequentially inserted) `AVAssets` from bunch of `.mp4` files I've loaded from disk into it.

Now I want to write out the resulting composition to disk, using the exact same settings as the source material (they are all generated by the same app, a security camera system).

`AVAssetExportSession` demands a named preset. I could just choose something like `AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality` but that implies a re-encoding, and I feel there should be a way to do this in a much more lossless way.

When I check the presets compatible with my composition, I get

> ["AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080", "AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4V720pHD",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4VAppleTV", "AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetHEVCHighestQuality", "AVAssetExportPreset640x480",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetAppleProRes422LPCM",
>   "AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160", "AVAssetExportPresetHEVC3840x2160",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4VWiFi",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4VCellular", "AVAssetExportPreset1280x720",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4V1080pHD",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4V480pSD", "AVAssetExportPreset960x540",
>   "AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4ViPod", "AVAssetExportPresetHEVC1920x1080"]

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`.
As the documentation states, it does not show up in results from `exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset` (for reasons not mentioned), but it generally works when writing mp4s or movs from compatible source assets, and it just collects and writes the sample data without any re-encoding.